# Understanding Models and ViewModels in MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I had been developping using WinForms for about a year now and I recently started discovering WPF. I have been more and more interested in this concept and started looking into the WPF's Framework MVVM.

### MVVM

1. We can say that **Windows**, **Pages**, **UserControls** in WPF are **Views**
2. But what  is the difference between Models and ViewModels?

I've looked at a lot of documentation on MSDN and some videos on YouTube trying to explain this.

If I understand correctly, the Models are basically the structure of your object (for example, Customers) and the ViewModels is what can work WITH the Customers object. Therefore I would bind my Window's DataContext to my ViewModel?

Comment: Try this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=MVVM&oq=MVVM&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1322j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). It looks like a lot of things that might help you.

Comment: @crashmstr Yes that's the first thing I researched two days ago. I was looking for a more concrete answer as to what the difference of the two are in a running project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the MVVM article from MSDN mag? I'm guessing yes, since you're mentioning customers... [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

If you've been coding OOP in winforms, then you've got classes to represent your data. That's nearly a 1:1 for what a model is. As a super-simplified way of looking at a viewmodel, think of it as the code that previously went into your code-behind for the controls of the page. It tells the view how to draw itself.. buttons to show/enable and the like.

So, in summary,

**model::data as viewmodel::form_controls**